# text box not working proper in contact form7 wordpress in chrome

Tags: wordpress

I am using contact form 7 in wordpress.

Basically, I have a text input. With that i am facing a weird issue on the input box. This behaviour happens only in chrome (I am using version 16.0.2).

To reproduce the issue:

Place the focus/cursor in the input box and type a few characters
without taking the focus out of the box, again click inside the text-input box
Try entering further text there is nothing displaying 
When i hover from text box contain display in text box..
again click in text box and trying to type any thing nothing act without get out from text box..

please help me ..

Comment: is there any live examples?

Comment: did you edit the plugin code?

Comment: this is my site url .. its in home page contact form .. check n help plz..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove float of text box.

```
.slider .form input {
   float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: how floating can cause such issues?

Answer (score 2):

I can see couple of errors in console. please fix these errors and then check the form functionality.

You have forgot to include bxslider core plugin but called it in script.js, also, you have to check the themepunch revolution slider code.

[image]

### **Update:**

Please remove `position:relative;` style from **wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css** stylesheet, and check. I am not sure why it is behaving like that due to `position` attribute!

Comment: `<span style="position: relative;"><input...></span>` - the problem for me in Wordpress Contact Forms 7 - "position: relative" for span element was causing the issue ... &*%% ... and I have no Idea, how it can have such impact! Remove "relative" to test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are including 3 core Jquery files in your theme...

So i think there is a jquery conflict problem.

```
1). '/themes/learning-center/js/jquery.min.js' 
     (2 times, 1 in header & 2nd in footer)

2). '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'
     (this is in header, and coming from `wp_head` obviously )
```

So remove your first `jquery.min.js` and try again...

Hope it work after removing first `.js`...