# WordPress contact form 7 text box not displaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am having problems viewing text in my contact form 7 text fields using WordPress.  The only browser I am having trouble viewing them in is Chrome. If I click into the text field and start typing nothing shows until I click out of the text field.  If I click into a text field and start typing then click into the next field and start typing nothing shows until clicking out of the text and somewhere else on the page? I have one other thread where someone had this issue but it has not helped me solve this problem.  The link is here [text box not working proper in contact form7 wordpress in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216911/text-box-not-working-proper-in-contact-form7-wordpress-in-chrome)

I have looked into trying to modify the css of this contact form but can't figure out how to edit it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome.

Comment: @rnevius try typing in the captcha field. And it's because of `position:relative;` on the `span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the following CSS rule...not even sure what it's doing in there:

```
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
```