# Chrome and Opera not displaying wordpress contact form 7 test box

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contacts

So this is a long standing problem that was addressed years ago at 
[WordPress contact form 7 text box not displaying in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638847/wordpress-contact-form-7-text-box-not-displaying-in-chrome)
What happens is that EVERY time the plugin upgrades this error pops up and text box will not display on Chrome or Opera. I for years have made the change recommended in the old post by replacing the style.css file with the old one. 
However in the latest update, which is ver. 4.7 my fix of replacing the style.css file with the old one with the fix has stop working. When I roll back to ver 4.6.1 all is good again.

Bottomline, I am looking for a permanent fix and to figure out why these browsers are only ones not liking my theme.

Comment: What do you mean "the fix has stop working"?  Are you seeing error messages?  Program hangs?

Comment: Sorry. Only in Chrome and Opera, the text box fields appear not to be present (blend into background coloring of form box). But, if I click into place where the text field should be and start typing, form actually accepts the typing, BUT nothing shows until I click out of the text field, and move to next field. So the plugin functions fine, and sends email, and reCaptcha all works fine. It is a formating problem of some sort that only manifests in Chrome and Opera browsers. No such problems on iPhones, Android, Firefox, iExplorer of any stripe.